# PHP: how to update data in an array which is inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

Following is my PHP code:

```
while($row = $resp->fetch_assoc())
{
    $itemArray = array(
      array(
        'name' => $row["product_name"],
        'id' => $row["id"],
        'image' => $row['images'],
        'discount' => $row["discount"],
        'quantity' => $min_quantity,
        'price' => $row["price"]
      )
    );
}

if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
{
    if(in_array($itemArray, $_SESSION["cart_item"]))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
        {
            if(in_array($item, $itemArray))
                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$item]["quantity"] = $min_quantity;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
}
```

After executing this code i am getting a response like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Girls Designer Dress
        [id] => 4
        [image] => s:146:"2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-07_am.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-08_am
.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-09_am.jpg";
        [discount] => 10
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 1200
    )

)
```

What I am trying to acheive is if user adds the same product in cart whose data we have got in response then instead of creating once more array and merging it one after another `i want to just update the quantity` of the same product from `1` to `2`.

I am stuck in this part of code

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item)
{
    if(in_array($item, $itemArray))
    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$item]["quantity"] = $min_quantity;
    break;
}
```

I have tried it many times that if same product is encountered then increment the quantity by 1 for the same product and don't create one more array.

Can anyone help with this logic and code?

Comment: What is the value of $_SESSION["cart-item"] ?   If it is an array with cart information then looping over it is not the way to go.

Comment: is there is no value then this will be added in it `Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Girls Designer Dress
        [id] => 4
        [image] => s:146:"2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-07_am.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-08_am
.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-09_am.jpg";
        [discount] => 10
        [quantity] => 1
        [price] => 1200
    )

)`  if there is present then the array will be updated and the array will extend from `0` to `1` like this from `[0] => Array` to `[1] => Array` i wan to update the value which is present in [0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is **$_SESSION["cart-item"]** a single Array like?

```
Array
(
    [name] => Girls Designer Dress
    [id] => 4
    [image] => s:146:"2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-07_am.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-08_am
.jpg,2017/march/meetfashion01-04-2017_12-19-09_am.jpg";
    [discount] => 10
    [quantity] => 1
    [price] => 1200
)
```

If so then don't call a foreach instead just check directly if that cart-item is in the $itemArray using [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

(The function search in a array and if needle is found return its index else return false).

```
$cartItemPosition = array_search($_SESSION['cart-item'], $itemArray);

if($cartItemPosition == false) {
  // Not found in array, so create new entry
  $itemArray.push($_SESSION['cart-item']);

}else {
  // Found in array so edit existing entry

    $itemArray[$cartItemPosition]['quantity'] = 999;  
}
```

Comment: and what if a new product is added then? will it create a new array and append it to previous once ?

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav . You would do that in the '// Not found' loop. Also why re-create a new array? just append it to the already existing one.

Comment: That one worked perfectly for me :) i was creating an additonal array

Answer (score 0):

The below works if `$itemArray` has only 1 item :

Change to :

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
    {
        if(in_array($itemArray[0], $_SESSION["cart_item"]))
            {
                foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $index => $item)
                    {
                        if(in_array($item, $itemArray))
                            $_SESSION["cart_item"][$index]["quantity"] = $_SESSION["cart_item"][$index]["quantity"] + 1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        else
            {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
            }
    }
else
    {
        $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
    }
```

- Added [0] in first if statement of `in_array`.
- Added `$index` in the foreach loop and used it.

Your code before never went to the if statement. If `$itemArray` is always containing an array inside an array (that's why we used [0]) then it should be like that.

If it is possible that `$itemArray` has more than 1 items then we will have to edit the answer as needed.

Also not sure, but if your `fetching loop` is possible to return more than one items then it's wrong becuse you will only have the last result. If you know that you will only have 1 result back then it's all good.

```
while($row = $resp->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $itemArray = array(
                             array(
                                    'name' => $row["product_name"],
                                    'id' => $row["id"],
                                    'image' => $row['images'],
                                    'discount' => $row["discount"],
                                    'quantity' => $min_quantity,
                                    'price' => $row["price"]
                                  )
                          );
    }
```